# CSS-only dropdown menu works fine but not in Edge

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I am working on a CSS-only dropdown menu. This is the code I am using now:

```css
.show
    { display: none;
}
 
.hide:focus + .show
    {display: block;
}
 
.hide:focus
    {display: none;
}
 
#ddm
    {display: none;
}
 
.hide:focus ~ #ddm
    {display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
<a href="#" class="hide">menu</a><a href="#" class="show">menu</A>
 
<div id="ddm">items</div>
</body>
```

It works heartily in all browsers except Microsoft Edge. That browser only shows the menu for a fraction of a second. :( Does anyone possibly know what is happening here? And how I can fix this? I appreciate all the help. Thank you very much!

Kind regards,
George.

Comment: I don't think I would recommend using the focus state to open a menu. Maybe try using a check box like this https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Comment: It doesn't work in Chrome (on Windows 10) either (Chrome/Edge are basically  the same). On focus you hide the menu with display:none - there's just a split second before that happens. Focus is problematic as @dantheman has mentioned another route would be preferable (so you can for example let the user click on one of the drop down items).

Comment: As you hide the link clicked on, it loses focus. This is why id doesn't work in 2 out of the 3 major browsers. Firefox seems to be the anomoly here.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer:** As per comments, without using JavaScript or a checkbox technique and using the `:focus` pseudo class, you could wrap the menus in a button and use that as the initial focus trigger.

```css
/* Menu styling for demo, change as needed */
#menu {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
}


/* Hidden initially */
#ddm,
#hide {
  display: none;
}


/* Prevent the 'show' element from triggering focus */
#show {
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* Show elements as needed */
#menu:focus~#ddm,
#menu:focus #hide,
#menu:not(:focus) #show,
#hide:focus #show {
  display: block;
}


/* Hide elements as needed */
#menu:focus #show,
#menu:not(:focus)~#hide,
#hide:focus #hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <!-- New button element to wrap around the two menus -->
  <button id="menu">
    <!-- Numbers in text added just to demonstrate the difference -->
    <a href="#" id="show">menu1</a>
    <a href="#" id="hide">menu2</a>
  </button>

  <div id="ddm">items</div>

</body>
```

---

**Original Answer:** Perhaps a simpler approach would fit your needs (unless you have a specific reason to use two menus that are hidden and shown). Just have one menu that is always shown, and toggle the items depending on its focus:

```css
#ddm {
  display: none;
}

.menu:focus~#ddm {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="#" class="menu">menu</a>
  <div id="ddm">items</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Katie. But I would like a second click on "menu" to make the items disappear again. I should have mentioned that. Sorry for that...

Comment: @George I see! I'll update my answer as soon as I get a chance. Do you only want the items to disappear when the menu is clicked, or both when it is clicked AND whenever the focus is lost (as they do in my answer)?

Comment: Thanks Katie. I would like my CSS code to behave exactly the same in Edge as it does now in Firefox and Explorer. That is: on loading page (initial state) only (hamburger) menu is visible.  A (first) click on menu shows the items. Another (second) click on menu makes item invisible again. Etc.

Preferably no solution with checkbox (input tag) or onclick (javascript), because of compatibility and Content-Security-Policy respectively.

And of course I'd like to see the css validate properly on https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_uri

Comment: Hi @George - I updated my answer and hope it meets your needs. I imagine there will be more complex styling in your project, but this might be a good starting point if you want to continue using focus and not checkbox or JavaScript. Cheers!

Comment: `a` is invalid content in a `button` : "Permitted content Phrasing content but there must be no Interactive content" from : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: Hi. I have tested whether the above button and div versions work... Safari on iPhone (iOS 9.3.5): button no, div yes. Safari on iPad (iOS 12.5.3): button no, div yes. Native browser on Android (4.4.4): button no, div yes. Edge (91.0.864.41) on Windows 10: button yes, div yes. Explorer (20H2) on Windows 10: button no, div yes. Firefox (89.0) on Windows 10: button yes, div yes. I have decided to use the div version. Thank you! :-) Kind regards, Greorge.

Answer (score 0):

I would still be using javascript or the checkbox method as they are more robust, but the following *could* work.

Use some creative positioning and the `:target` pseudo class, which selects the element referenced by `href=#someId` and then sibling selectors. Then the id for the burger menu is added to the show link `href` which is also better semantics. The hide/show buttons will need to be added *after* the menu element then repositioned with `position:absolute`.

```css
/*Position everything relative to nav*/
nav {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1.25em;
}

/*Position our show/hide elements*/
.show,.hide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/*Hide burger and button */
#ddm, #ddm:not(:target) ~ .hide {
  display: none;
}

/*Show Burger when show clicked*/
#ddm:target {
  display: block;
}

/*HIde Burger when not show clicked*/
#ddm:target~.show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- Nav Used For Positioning -->
  <nav>
    <div id="ddm">Burger</div>
    <a href="#ddm" class="show">Show Burger</a>
    <a href="#" class="hide">Hide Burger</a>
  </nav>
</body>
```